# Python variable gets assigned before function ends

Tags: python

I am having an issue where a variable is getting assigned a value before my function fully ends. There must be some behind the scenes stuff going on that I'm not aware of.

```
def find_x(y):
    if y:
        found_it = y
        return found_it
    else:
        create_it(y)

def create_it(y):
    # .. create database entry, when done call find_x to find what just got created
    find_x()

my_stuff = find_x('y')
print(my_stuff)
```

When this is first executed and I know that 'y' does not exist, 'my_stuff' returns None. Almost like it's getting assigned a None value when create_x() exits, but I expect 'my_stuff' to not get assigned until find_x() gets called and returns something.

Comment: Sounds like an x/'y' problem  ;)

Comment: You pass a non-empty string to `find_x`, which is a truthy value, and so `find_x` just returns it. `create_it` never gets called.

Comment: You never *return* the value returned by `create_it`; you just fall through to the end of the function and let the implicit `None` be returned. Same for `create_it`; you don't actually return the value produced by `find_x`.

Comment: Yeah I didn't realize that when no return is present, python assigns None to the variable. I've revised my code and it seems to be working

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not returning anything if `y` is not found. Just return `create_it(y)` method and it should work.